# Rails relational issue - Find user's next outing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mysql, relational-database

I have an outings table, which basically holds some information about an 'outing'. These outings then have crews, which have users (through crew_users)

Just as a note, outings have many crews, so there's an outing_id in the crews table

Now, I need to find the user's *next* outing, as in the first outing where  `outing.start_time > Time.now`

I've got this in my user.rb model:

```
has_many :crew_users
has_many :crews, :through => :crew_users
has_many :outings, :through => :crews
```

And when I try to do this:

```
>> Users.find(1).outings
```

I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql::Error: Unknown column 'crews.user_id' 
in 'where clause': SELECT `outings`.* FROM `outings`  INNER JOIN `crews` ON
`outings`.id = `crews`.outing_id    WHERE ((`crews`.user_id = 1))
```

Anyone any ideas? Like I said, my goal is to get the user's *next* outing from the current time so there may very well be a much better to go about this!

Comment: This might be an issue with building a double :through relationship. I've had trouble with them before. Maybe someone can confirm this is the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and reverse this is if doing a double `:through` is out of the question by filtering the Outing records instead. The SQL for this would look something like:

```
SELECT outings.id FROM outings
  LEFT JOIN crews ON crews.id=outings.crew_id
  LEFT JOIN crews_users ON crews_users.crew_id=crews.id
  WHERE crews_users.user_id=? AND start_time>=NOW()
  ORDER BY created_at
  LIMIT 1
```

The quick and dirty approach is to run this and extract the outing_id value you need, then call `Outing.find` with that.

Comment: Is it possible to just use that query but by doing `Outing.find_by_sql()` ?

Comment: Just as a note, outings have many crews, so there's an outing_id in the crews table.

Comment: ActiveRecord sometimes pretends it knows what you're talking about when you define relationships, but when you actually exercise them it falls flat on its face. If you've got a three level join that'll probably do it. `find_by_sql` could be what you need, too, if you can tweak the query enough.